# How to disable Openshift Wordpress app url from getting indexed in Google

Tags: php, wordpress, google-search-console

I'm running a Wordpress site on free openshift by redhat.

I added the custom domain and everything is working fine.

The problem is that both of my urls: `www.namanboard.com(custom)` + `nb-namanwp.rhcloud.com`(openshift app) are getting indexed in google.

And it affects my SEO. my website is available to google at two different urls with same content. I want to disable the openshift app url i.e `nb-namanwp.rhcloud.com` from getting indexed in google.

I'm unable to add it to google search console at I can't verify my identity there.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You must to upload a file in the `nb-namanwp.rhcloud.com` server. The file needs to be called `robots.txt` and with this content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And google stop to indexing. To remove the last indexed pages you need to login into webmaster tools account and search the "Remove pages" section. You must to define the whole correct URL to remove and wait few days. Ces't fini.

Good luck